# What is the meaning of "ConnectEx tcp: The semaphore timeout period has expired."

Tags: windows, tcp, go

I write a simple go program which runs on windows and tests whether the remote port is active:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main(){
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "192.168.23.191:3403")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        conn.Close()
    }
}
```

Now, the remote port is closed. I run it first time, and the error is:

```
dial tcp 192.168.23.191:3403: ConnectEx tcp: The remote computer refused the network connection.
```

Then I continue to run it, the error is changed to:

```
dial tcp 192.168.23.191:3403: ConnectEx tcp: The semaphore timeout period has expired.
```

Why the Dial returns "ConnectEx tcp: The semaphore timeout period has expired."? And what is the meaning of this error?

Answer (score 1):

The call to `net.Dial()` has a timeout which expired.

As seen [here](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer), the `Dialer` struct has a `Timeout` field which defines the *maximum amount of time that a `Dial()` will wait for a connect to complete*.

Comment: Why timeout returns "The semaphore timeout period has expired."? I think form your explanation, the error should be "Connection timeout", what does semaphore refer to?

Comment: [**semaphore**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) _In computer science, particularly in operating systems, a semaphore is a variable or abstract data type that is used for controlling access, by multiple processes, to a common resource in a parallel programming or a multi user environment._  It sounds like perhaps further downstream there is a semaphore implemented to control concurrent access on the network - like `net.Dial()`, a semaphore always implements a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

`net.Dial` (with some intermediate functions) [ends up](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/release-branch.go1.5/src/net/fd_windows.go#322) calling [`ConnectEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a Windows specific extension to BSD Sockets.
If the connection cannot be established (Windows conforms to [RFC 1122 Section 4.2.3.5](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1122.txt) and tries [multiple](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938209.aspx) times) ConnectEx fails with `ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT` (AFAIK that isn't officially documented, one would expect an error like `WSAETIMEDOUT`).

So that error means that the port is closed.

On Windows 8 and newer Versions of Windows it is possible to [change the connections settings for a single socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj710203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if you want to do this in Go you have to do the version check and calls for yourself.